# Solve::svars from a system of two equations in two variables

Tags: equation-solving

I have a system of equations to solve. It looks like a system of equation that could be solved by hand, but Mathematica returns a 'Solve::svars' message:

```
Solve[
  (2 (px + 5*py))/(3*px) + (3*px + 2*py)/(px + py) == 4 && 
  (px + 5*py)/(3*py) + (3*px + 2*py)/(px + py) == 7,
  {px, py}
]
```

Why am I getting this message?

Comment: `Reduce`  work fine.

Comment: What is the output of your input?  I get this result: `{{py -> 1/10 (-3 px - Sqrt[19] px)}, {py -> 1/10 (-3 px + Sqrt[19] px)}}`. If you use e.g. `Reduce` instead of `Solve` you'll get an unambiguous result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we apply FullSimplify to your equations, we see that they reduce to a single equation in two variables:

```
FullSimplify[
  (2 (px + 5*py))/(3*px) + (3*px + 2*py)/(px + py) == 4 &&
  (px + 5*py)/(3*py) + (3*px + 2*py)/(px + py) == 7
]

(* Out:
px (1/py + 3/(px + py)) == 10
*)
```

... so the system is underdetermined, i.e. there isn't enough information to extract  explicit values for both px and py; you can only obtain one as a function of the other, if at all. That's what Solve does, but it is warning you of this fact.

`Reduce` will handle this as well:

```
Reduce[
  (2 (px + 5*py))/(3*px) + (3*px + 2*py)/(px + py) == 4 &&
  (px + 5*py)/(3*py) + (3*px + 2*py)/(px + py) == 7,
  {px, py}
]

(* Out: 
(py == 1/10 (-3 px - Sqrt[19] px) || py == 1/10 (-3 px + Sqrt[19] px)) && px != 0
*)
```

---

You can also take a look at the shape of your equations separately, as follows:

```
equations = {
  (2 (px + 5*py))/(3*px) + (3*px + 2*py)/(px + py) == 4,
  (px + 5*py)/(3*py) + (3*px + 2*py)/(px + py) == 7
};

Factor /@ Simplify[equations]

(* Out:
{(px^2 - 6 px py - 10 py^2)/(px (px + py)) == 0,
 (px^2 - 6 px py - 10 py^2)/(py (px + py)) == 0}
*)
```

So your equations are similar to solving the following **single equation**:

```
Solve[px^2 - 6 px py - 10 py^2 == 0, {px, py}]

(*Out:
{{py -> 1/10 (-3 px - Sqrt[19] px)}, {py -> 1/10 (-3 px + Sqrt[19] px)}}
*)
```

Comment: Or `Solve` for a single variable, i.e., `Solve[eqns, py]` or `Solve[eqns, px]`

Comment: Or `Solve[eqns]` or `DeleteCases[Map[ToRules, Level[Reduce[eqns, vars], {1}]], {}]`.